# Cant import any packages in jupyter notebook after updating python to 3.7

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, python-3.7

After updating python to 3.7 i ran into so many problems with jupyter notebook 
1) Cant run python in powershell or cmd because im getting this error

```
   python : The term 'python' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, 
function, script
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was 
included,
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ python
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (python:String) [], 
CommandNotFoundException

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

2) Cant import most of the packages, Im getting Import error: DLL load failed, I tried "from scipy.stats.stats import pearsonr" and i got this error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-0ebd78c1f4f1> in <module>()
----> 1 from scipy.stats.stats import pearsonr

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\__init__.py in <module>()
    343 from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import
    344 
--> 345 from .stats import *
    346 from .distributions import *
    347 from .morestats import *

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py in <module>()
    167 from scipy._lib.six import callable, string_types
    168 from scipy._lib._version import NumpyVersion
--> 169 import scipy.special as special
    170 import scipy.linalg as linalg
    171 from . import distributions

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\special\__init__.py in <module>()
    638 from .sf_error import SpecialFunctionWarning, SpecialFunctionError
    639 
--> 640 from ._ufuncs import *
    641 
    642 from .basic import *

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: I'm afraid my answer might not have been relevant as you are using Anaconda, something I know little about. I would suggest checking your system paths under system in the control panel and make sure that they are correct. Python typically uninstalls the previous version and installs the new version; with Anaconda, I'm not sure what it does. If that is the case, you may need to reinstall the required site-packages using `pip3`

Comment: How have you upgraded your python?

Comment: @FlyingTeller i uninstalled the previous one and installed the new one. I got errors. So again installed the old one and updated with "conda update python" but still getting the same error

Comment: so you did a fresh anaconda installation and then immediately did the update python? I think then, that the error might be that some packages were not updated correctly. I would suggest for you to try with either miniconda, or freshly install anaconda and then create a virtual environment with python 3.7